# How to make public only one file of a private git repository?

Tags: git, github, repository, bitbucket

From my private git repository, I would like to make a single file publicly available. Is there a way to achieve this in say GitHub, BitBucket or elsewhere?

Let me be more precise. I have a Latex project containing, say:

```
main.tex
chapters/chapter1.tex
...
chapters/chapterN.tex 
main.pdf
```

I would like to make `main.pdf` publicly available and distribute a link pointing to it, while keeping the remaining files private. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 6):

It is not possible to do it with GIT.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, it's better to use some tools which can automatically export your file to another public git repo.

You can use [git export tool](https://github.com/open-condo-software/gitexporter) for that.

You need to create `gitexporter.config.json` like so:

```
{
    "forceReCreateRepo": true,
    "targetRepoPath": "my-open-source-repo",
    "sourceRepoPath": ".",
    "allowedPaths": ["main.pdf"]
}
```

and then run `npx giteporter gitexporter.config.json`.

These tools create a new repo `my-open-source-repo` with the same commit history as your current `.` repo. The `my-open-source-repo` repo will contain only your `main.pdf` file and its history.